# Changing file extensions in a folder using c#

Tags: c#

I have files in a folder and I want to change their extensions they are like `123.pdf.kayityok ;` they are already changed so what I want to do is make them `.pdf` again without `.kayityok` so after I choose folder and run the program it will make the file like `123.pdf`. I havent used c# in a long time so please explain things in details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should think, search, read and try, before asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

There is: `Path.ChangeExtension` method.

```
var result = Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".jpg");
```

In the case if you also want to physically change the extension, you could use File.Move method:

`File.Move(myffile, Path.ChangeExtension(myffile, ".jpg"))`;

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) to rename the file. If you supply the same directory in which the file already is, this will only rename the file then.

For example:

```
File.Move(@"C:\dir\123.pdf.kayityok", @"C:\dir\123.pdf");
```

Comment: i have many files in that folder and names are not stable so i need to read the names first and that is the main problem i am having right now, i already found renaming examples in other questions

Comment: Well, you can get list of all files via Directory.EnumerateFiles method. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Path class of the .NET framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx).
The ChangeExtension() methos could help you (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx)

Regards,